# Trouble dynamically adding fields with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I'm dynamically generating nested form fields using the cocoon gem as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @incorporation do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company| %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add ID', company, :persons, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
    <%= company.simple_fields_for :persons do |person|%>
        <%= render 'person_fields', f: person %>
    <% end =%>
  <% end =%>
<% end =%>
```

And `_person_fields` is (currently) as follows:

```
<div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><%= f.input :fname, input_html: {class: 'form-input form-control'}, label: "First Name" %></div>
</div>
```

The `link_to_add_association` should, through the cocoon gem and javascript, add another row of `_person_fields` to the form

**The problem** is that the button in fact adds nothing.  Rather, it seems to just bring me to the top of the page.  I know that javascript is installed (and working) via therubyracer gem.  I know javascript is working because I've got bootstrap running on the site.

I know cocoon works and I've used it on a few apps.  Does anyone see something that I might be leaving out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to [RFTM](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)  I was missing the line:

```
//= require cocoon
```

in my `application.js`

I figure I'll keep this question up in case anyone else needs the reminder as well :-)

Comment: I am having the same issue in an engine. Did you tried it using engines? Thanks

Comment: @Moh I didn't, but I imagine the same would apply.  Also, cocoon can do some weird stuff when you don't have the appropriate html structure.  Feel free to post a question and I'd be glad to have a look.